# Using shell script to extract text file to a variable

Tags: linux, shell

I have a set of data in a text file.

```
aaa:bbb:ccc
ddd:fff:ggg
```

, seperated by ':' and I have a variables 1,2 and 3. How to seprate the data like lets say I am intrested in only aaa line. So I will have 1=aaa,2=bbb and 3=ccc.

Tried using

`1=grep "$a" textfile.txt | awk -F ':' '{print $1}'`

`2=grep "$a" textfile.txt | awk -F ':' '{print $2}'`

`3=grep "$a" textfile.txt | awk -F ':' '{print $3}'`

but does not work. Please advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
VAR1=$(grep "$a" textfile.txt | awk -F ':' '{print $1}')
VAR2=$(grep "$a" textfile.txt | awk -F ':' '{print $2}')
VAR3=$(grep "$a" textfile.txt | awk -F ':' '{print $3}')
```

Your variable must not be just numbers and you need to set the output of the grep to the var (not the command itself)

**EDIT**:

You could also use the following:

```
VAR1=$(awk -F ':' '{print $1}' textfile.txt)
VAR2=$(awk -F ':' '{print $2}' textfile.txt)
VAR3=$(awk -F ':' '{print $3}' textfile.txt)
```

Comment: hmm...how to store numbers?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest you can get these variables is by using BASH array using read bulletin:

```
> read -a arr< <(IFS=':' && grep "aaa" file)
> printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the positional parameters, you can use a subshell and the IFS variable to extract the values:

```
$ line="aaa:bbb:ccc"
$ set -- $(IFS=:; echo $line)
$ echo $1
aaa
$ echo $2
bbb
$ echo $3
ccc
```

To iterate over the file, using the positional parameters is needlessly opaque:

```
while IFS=: read -r a b c; do
    echo "$((++line)), a=$a b=$b c=$c"
done < file
```

```
1, a=aaa b=bbb c=ccc
2, a=ddd b=fff c=ggg
```

Comment: is it possible to perform arithmetic operations as well?

Comment: yes. http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic and http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arithmetic-Expansion